# How can I use Url::fromRoute() in a test?

Tags: testing

If I crate the class for test like:

```php
class ReturnHandlerTest extends OrderKernelTestBase {

  protected static $modules = [
    'commerce_payment',
    'commerce_payment_example',
  ];

  protected function setUp(): void {
    parent::setUp();
  }

}
```

And if I want to use

```php
 Url::fromRoute('commerce_payment.checkout.return', $arguments)
   ->setOptions(['absolute' => true])
   ->toString()
```

In the test, I get this exception.

> Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: Route "commerce_payment.checkout.return" does not exist.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I should include the module "commerce_checkout".

```
 protected static $modules = [
    'commerce_payment',
    'commerce_payment_example',
    'commerce_checkout',
  ];
```